# The Stack Overflow blog lacks findable search or pagination

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog

There's been a push to try to move over more communication to Stack Overflow's blog. There are a few fundamental issues that seem to make it unsuitable for the task, or for that matter, any purpose at the moment

[image: Blog thumbnails]

There is no search. The top left link oddly enough traps you in a spiral back to the blog, though I guess that almost makes sense for other pages (maybe add a .blog to the logo to manage expectations). The stackoverflow.com on the right looks lonely and forlorn, and almost an afterthought for your star product.

[image]

There is no pagination.

Practically there is no 'organic' way to refer to an old post, or to find anything but the latest or "popular" posts from the front page.

Fundamentally - folks can't find previous posts easily, which means that referencing old blog posts is nearly impossible.

This might need to be fixed if folks are going to be reading anything other than the latest marketing fluff piece on the blog.

Also the last three items being inexplicably smaller bothers me for some reason.

Comment: The only way I can ever find Blog posts is by searching for MSE posts that reference them, which is obviously far from ideal :-/

Comment: Note that pagination does actually work if you want posts within a certain year, e.g. [2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/), and search works if you know [the link](https://stackoverflow.blog/?s). It seems like these features, while present by default, were actively removed for some reason.

Comment: Also tried to report an HTML markup bug in comments but even with backticks it all just got mangled. No preview, and no way to edit after-the-fact. The system needs a "bit" of an update if we're to start using it in anger.

Comment: Erik Reinstate MonicA is correct. I made [a list of all of them](http://pmortensen.eu/world2/?p=89).

Comment: @Lightness Races with Monica: Yes, they ought to add [a plugin that allows editing of comments](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-have-a-WordPress-based-blog-where-users-can-edit-their-own-comments-at-least-within-the-first-15-minutes-E-g-is-there-a-high-quality-plugin-for-this) (at least for a number of hours or days). Though it is not clear how this could play along with the current comment moderation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We hope to be able to address these and other UX concerns on the blog soon.

Comment: @YaakovEllis so you're assigned as the chief (and only?) developer of winter bash, you're assigned as a blog developer... is there anything you're not part of?? :-D

Comment: Project 66 obviously :D

Comment: [The HTTPS version](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2019/12/10/the-secret-index-of-all-stack-overflow-blog-posts/) in case it doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just following up, search is back and there is a more robust pagination as we have [redesigned the blog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393712/updates-to-the-stack-overflow-blog).

Comment: I quite literally have nothing to complain about. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There is pagination available when browsing a certain tag. In this case I was at https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/announcements/page/2/ 
[image]

However the arrows that accompany the "Older Articles" and "Newer Articles" (whats with the camels btw?), are obscured by some whitespacing.

Comment: There is also pagination without a tag (all posts) for each year. For 2019, the newest is [https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/page/1/](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/page/1/) and the oldest [https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/page/22/](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/page/22/) (as of today - if more blog posts are added this year, there may be more than 22 pages). I have compiled [a list of all of them](http://pmortensen.eu/world2/?p=89)...

Comment: [The HTTPS version](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2019/12/10/the-secret-index-of-all-stack-overflow-blog-posts/) in case it doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 3):

> This might need to be fixed if folks are going to be reading anything
>   other than the latest marketing fluff piece on the blog.

This is my assessment also, and my understanding is that *may* be an intentional choice...

Supporting this assessment is that some of the recents posts that relate to controversial issues here are very low-profile (small, have no images, etc.)

**Note that if you click on a post, you can then click on one of its tags and use a basic pagination there (Older/Newer articles).**

To go through actual page numbers, you'll need to mess with the URL.

Example:

```
https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/announcements/page/5/
```

Comment: It is [not only for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339980/the-stack-overflow-blog-lacks-findable-search-or-pagination#comment1136195_339983); all blog posts can be seen (sample: [https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/page/16/](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/page/16/)). I made [a list of all of them](http://pmortensen.eu/world2/?p=89) (all the way back to 2008).

Comment: @petermortensen I would definitely upvote that if you added it as an answer!

Comment: [The HTTPS version](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2019/12/10/the-secret-index-of-all-stack-overflow-blog-posts/) in case it doesn't redirect.